# How can I search in a ListCollectionView?

Tags: c#, wpf, startswith, listcollectionview

Until yesterday I used a ListView and bound it to a List<>.
Then I read in some articles that it makes sense to bind the ListView to a ListCollectionView for easy filtering. I did this and it works fine.
But now I don’t know how I can find an item in the ListCollectionView.
Until yesterday I used this code, and it works with the List:

```
List<Artist> selectedArtistsList;
var item = selectedArtistsList.OrderBy(artist => artist.ArtistShowName).FirstOrDefault(artist => artist.ArtistShowName.StartsWith(FindInSelection1.Text, StringComparison.CurrentCultureIgnoreCase));
```

But it seems for a ListCollectionView there is nothing similar like StartsWith
How can I search in a (filtered) ListCollectionView?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`ListCollectionView` implements `IEnumerable` so just [cast](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb341406(v=vs.110).aspx) it to `IEnumerable<Artist>`

```
var artist = listCollectionView
                 .Cast<Artist>()
                 .OrderBy(artist => artist.ArtistShowName)
                 .FirstOrDefault(artist => artist.ArtistShowName.StartsWith(FindInSelection1.Text, StringComparison.CurrentCultureIgnoreCase));
```